# Facebook and Twitter Integration with Unity for iOS and Android

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, twitter, unity-game-engine

I am new bee in Unity Development and developing an app in which I want to share a Image with Text on user's wall On Facebook and Twitter. I googled and got few links which says that buys plugins [Prime31](http://www.prime31.com/unity/), I getting bit confuse on Followings.

1. How to Integrate Facebook and Twitter in Unity without buying any external plugins, like we can do easily in xcode.
2. If there are available free of cost Plugins, What are the links for tutorial and any helping Material, so that i can easily hookup with my app.
3. Can we do this task without plugins like in xcode we just need Facebook SDKs and same with twitter.

Comment: i am also searching for any available free way to get connected with facebook in unity ...sadly didnt get any reference yet than prime31

Comment: I am following this one "http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html" its working perfectly fine

Comment: can you please explain it lit bit more (as i am newbie in unity) how are you to integrating facebook to unity?

Comment: Actually this is plugin for xcode and Facebook is not integrated with Unity its facebook integration with xcode. I just use message passing from unity to xcode. Here is link "http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/27026/api-integration-for-unity.html" where you find more simple steps to follow. I am also new bee and i just follow whole steps its not diffult seriously :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)?
Documentations are [here](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki).

Comment: I think this is in Objective c, not for Unity(C#, Javascript). How can i hook this up with Unity3d.

Comment: @josh why you accepted answer if it is not correct one?

Comment: Because this give me way to track my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try [UniShare](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/search/unishare), a sharekit for unity3d, both iOS, Android support, include twitter, facebook, linkedin, etc.

Comment: Dead link. UniShare seems to have disappeared entirely from the store.

Answer (score 1):

[Let's Tweet in Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/536)

Haven't tested yet... but I'll post an update on my findings.

[Facebook Unity SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=SDK_list)

It's the official SDK published by Facebook itself. [Here's a tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial).

Comment: I opted to use Let's Tweet In Unity, but will need to reach out to the author. I tried to extended this library to retrieve the current user's profile information, but I haven't been able to get around the authorization errors. It's frustrating, because I can post tweets all day long, but can't retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SocialAuth

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

You can integrate Facebook , twitter , linkedin , myspace